# Can we prove the following convergence theorem for semi-groups of a Markov chain?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Following this question: [The relation between the semi-groups and transition matrix of a Markov chain.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4551582/the-relation-between-the-semi-groups-and-transition-matrix-of-a-markov-chain).

I am still confused about the notations between the transition matrix and semi-groups of a Markov chain.

There is a well-known result about mixing time as follows.

> Let $X$ be an irreducible and aperiodic Markov chain on a finite state space with invariant distribution $\pi$. Then there exist $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $C>0$ s.t. for all $x, y$
> $$
> \max_x \|P^t(x, \cdot)-\pi\|_{TV}\le C\alpha ^t
> $$

Now, I try to prove the similar result in a version for semi-groups of the Markov chain. Let $P_tf(x):=E[f(X_t)|X_0=x]$ be the semi-groups of Markov chain $X_t$. Let $\pi$ be invariant distribution so that $\pi(f)=\pi(P_tf)$ for all smooth functions $f$ where $\mu(f):=\int f d\mu$.

Can we similar prove that there exist $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $C>0$ so that
$$
\max_{\|f\|=1}\|P_tf(x)-\pi(f)\|_{TV}\le C\alpha ^t?
$$

---

Assume that $\pi(f)=0$.
Do we have
$$
|P_tf(x)-\pi(f)|=|\sum_y [P^t(x,y)f(y)-\pi(y)f(y)]|\le 2\|f\|_\infty \max_{\|f\|=1}\|P_tf(x)-\pi(f)\|_{TV}\le C\alpha ^t
$$

So
$$
\max_{\|f\|=1}\|P_tf(x)-\pi(f)\|_{TV}=0.5\sum_x|P_tf(x)-\mu(f)|\le 0.5\sum_x C\alpha^t?
$$